# Trying to split a URL at the ? character

Tags: javascript

I have what is a stupidly simple problem I just can't get to work. I want to get the current URL, split it at the ? so I can separate the URL from the querystring.

```
    var fullurl = window.location.href.toString();
    var sections = fullurl.Split('?');
```

But it keeps erroring that `fullurl.Split is not a function`

It's annoyingly basic. I assume because the URL is a Location object the splie won't work and I've tried all sorts to try and get it as a string so I can split it.

Any pointers?

Comment: Should be a lowercase `s` in split. i.e. - `var sections = fullurl.split('?');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. The method is called [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) not `Split`.

But you shouldn't be reinventing the wheel. JavaScript has built in methods for handling query strings.

`window.location` will give you a [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) which has a `search` property that will give you the query string and a `searchParams` property that will give you a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

Using these will save you from having a fragment identifier mixed up in your query string, and will parse any special characters in the URL for you.

```js
const fullurl = new URL("http://example.com/foo/bar?query=1&other=this+has+spaces+in+it#fragment-id-too"); // window.location
const qs = fullurl.search;
console.log(qs);
const other = fullurl.searchParams.get('other');
console.log(other);
```

Comment: You should instead of an answer perhaps of added a comment and closed as "typo"

Comment: Not to mention the question was already closed when he answered...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss — While a *literal* answer would be just dealing with a typo, the OP's approach was wrong, so properly solving the problem isn't addressing a typo (which is why I instead answered with a frame challenge).